# Linearly independent functions evaluated at random points create full rank matrices

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, pr.probability, measure-concentration

Assume $f_1, f_2,...,f_n: \mathbb{R}^d\mapsto\mathbb{R}^d$ are linearly independent functions. Now let $w_1,w_2,..,w_k\in\mathbb{R}^d$ be i.i.d. Gaussian random vectors distributed as $\mathcal{N}(0,\mathbf{I}_d)$ and $v_1,\ldots,v_k\in\mathbb{R}$ are i.i.d. Radamacher random variables ($\pm 1$ with equal probability). I want to show that as long as $kd\ge n$ then with high probability the matrix

\begin{align*}
\begin{bmatrix}
v_1f_1(\mathbf{w}_1) & v_1f_2(\mathbf{w}_1) & \ldots & v_1f_n(\mathbf{w}_1)\\
v_2f_1(\mathbf{w}_2) & v_2f_2(\mathbf{w}_2) & \ldots & v_2f_n(\mathbf{w}_2)\\
\vdots & \vdots & \ddots & \vdots\\
v_kf_1(\mathbf{w}_k) & v_kf_2(\mathbf{w}_k) & \ldots & v_kf_n(\mathbf{w}_k)
\end{bmatrix}\in\mathbb{R}^{kd\times n}
\end{align*}
is full rank

Comment: What do you mean by "linearly independent functions"? If it's just that there's no linear combination that vanishes identically, then it can still be that $f_n$ vanishes in a ball of radius $e^n$ around the origin. Which means that with overwhelming probability your matrix will have a zero column.

Comment: yes no linear combination that vanishes identically. To avoid pathological cases like you state above. Let's assume f is sufficiently nice that this doesn't happen e.g. f is smooth and differentiable. Specifically I'm interested in the case where $f_i(w_j)=\phi'(w_j^Tx_i)x_i$ with $\phi(z)=\log(1+e^z)$

Comment: and what are $x_i$?

Comment: $x_1,...,x_n\in\mathbb{R}^d$ are n points in $\mathbb{R}^d$ none of which can be written as a positive multiple of the other (i.e. $x_i=\alpha x_j$ for some positive $\alpha$. See https://mathoverflow.net/questions/336543/linear-independence-of-functions for a related question of mine about the independent part.